# Limiting search results Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to limit the search result in the Javascript file, my JS file details as following:

```
    /* JS File */
   <script> 
    // Start Ready
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // Icon Click Focus
        $('div.icon').click(function(){
            $('input#search').focus();
        });

        // Live Search
        // On Search Submit and Get Results
        function search() {
            var query_value = $('input#search').val();
            $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
            if(query_value !== ''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: { query: query_value },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("ul#results").html(html);
                    }
                });
            }return false;    
        }

        $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
            // Set Timeout
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

            // Set Search String
            var search_string = $(this).val();

            // Do Search
            if (search_string == '') {
                $("ul#results").fadeOut();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $("ul#results").fadeIn();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
                $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
            };
        });

    });
</script
```

I just need to add similar to following code to be able to load a loading images before the result and limit the results into five or whatever, and if possible add load more later.

```
    <script>
function loadSearch(query) {
    document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
    if (typeof xhr != "undefined") {
        xhr.abort();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    if (query.length >= 3) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#moreResults').slideDown(300);
            $('#search_results').slideDown(500).html('<br /><p align="center"><img src="http://www.tektontools.com/images/loading.gif"></p>');
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.tektontools.com/search_results.inc.php?query='+encodeURIComponent(query),
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#search_results").html(data);
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    } else {
        unloadSearch();
    }
}
function unloadSearch() {
    document.body.style.overflow='';
    $('#search_results').delay(100).slideUp(300);
    $('#moreResults').delay(100).slideUp(300);
}
</script>
```

I have got the 2nd code from another template page, and I am just failing to adjust it to fit my search template (1st code), I'd appreciate it if someone could help me to adjust it, thanks a lot.

Comment: you mean you want a kind of pagination?

Comment: I think you need something in the backend code for pagination. Your PHP code should support paging with at least two basic parameters `page_id` and `limit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on the javascript side, you can use [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "search.php",
   data: { query: query_value },
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
      $("ul#results").html(html.slice(0, 5);
   }
});
```

I would personally suggest that you do the limiting of rows on the server side to minimize the amount of data you transfer between the client and the server.

Comment: would you please, please add up this "slice" code on the proper position on the 1st code, and change the variable ("#search_results") into the proper one to fit the 1st code, thanks a lot for your response already anyway.

Comment: @beginner I did little edit on the code part of the answer. Hope you can now properly place it into your code.